# Angle of orthogonal projection and given vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, orthogonality

I am unsure how to prove the following exercise:

> Let $V$ be an Euclidean vector space, $U\subset V$ a finite-dimensional subspace and $x\in V\setminus U^\bot$. Let $p\in U$ be the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $U$.
>   Prove: Out of all vectors $y\in U\setminus \{0\}$, $p$ has the smallest angle with $x$.

My thoughts:
We know that $\|x-p\| = \min\{\|x-u\|: u\in U\}$, i.e.
$$\|x-p\| \leq \|x-y\| \, \forall y\in U$$
so maybe we can use that.
The problem is that I don't really know how to approach problems regarding the angle;
the only things I know about the angle is
$$\cos \varphi = \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$$
and playing with the $\arccos$ here is probably not the right approach.
Effectively, I have to show
$$\arccos \frac{\langle x, p \rangle}{\|x\|\|p\|} \leq \arccos \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|} \, \forall y\in U$$
but there must be an easier way to approach this. Can you help me maybe?

Comment: If $\arccos \frac{\langle x, p \rangle}{\|x\|\|p\|} \leq \arccos \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$ then $\frac{\langle x, p \rangle}{\|x\|\|p\|} \ge \frac{\langle x, y \rangle}{\|x\|\|y\|}$

Comment: True. That makes the whole thing easier.

Answer (score 0):

The proposition is false as stated. For any $\lambda\gt0$, the vectors $y$ and $\lambda y$ have the same angle with $x$, so a vector that minimizes this angle cannot be unique.

Answer (score 0):

While the proposition is false as stated, we can still prove the following:

> Let $V$ be a Euclidean vector space, $U \subset V$ a finite dimensional subspace, and $x \in V \setminus U^{\perp}$. Let $p \in U$ be the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $U$. Then, for all $u \in U \setminus \{0\}$, the angle formed by $x$ and $u$ is greater than the angle formed by $x$ and $p$, with equality iff $u = \lambda p$ for $\lambda \in (0, \infty)$.

First, we show for all $u \in U$, $\langle x, u \rangle = \langle p, u \rangle$. We can see this in two ways: First, since $p$ is the orthogonal projection, $\|x - (p + \varepsilon u)\| \geq \|x - p\|$ for all $\varepsilon$, so
\begin{align*}
\| x - (p + \varepsilon u)\|^2 \geq \|x - p\|^2 &\iff \langle (x - p) - \varepsilon u, (x - p) - \varepsilon u\rangle \geq \langle x - p, x - p \rangle \\
&\iff -2 \varepsilon \langle x - p, u \rangle + \varepsilon^2 \langle u, u \rangle \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Since this holds for all $\varepsilon$, the linear term must vanish, hence $\langle x - p, u \rangle = 0$, or $\langle x, u \rangle = \langle p, u \rangle$. For finite dimensional $U$, we can also see this by explicitly writing an orthonormal basis $(e_1, \ldots, e_k)$ of $U$, and then writing down $\langle x, u \rangle$ and $\langle p, u \rangle$ with respect to this basis.

We can then use this property to show our claim. Note that the angle between $x$ and $u$ is given by $\arccos \frac{\langle x, u \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \langle u, u \rangle}}$. However as $\arccos$ is decreasing, minimizing the angle is equivalent to maximizing $\frac{\langle x, u \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \langle u, u \rangle}}$. Now,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\langle x, u \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \langle u, u \rangle}} = \frac{\langle p, u \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \langle u, u \rangle}} \underset{CS}\leq \frac{\sqrt{\langle p, p \rangle \langle u, u \rangle}}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \langle u, u \rangle}} = \frac{\sqrt{\langle p, p \rangle}}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}} = \frac{\langle x, p \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \langle p, p \rangle}},
\end{align*}
where we used our identity to establish the first and last equalities, and also Cauchy-Schwarz in the middle. This proves that $p$ attains the maximum angle over all of $U$.

Moreover, for equality to holds, we must have equality in Cauchy-Schwarz, so $u = \lambda p$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, and also $\langle u, p \rangle$ must be greater than 0, so $\lambda \in (0, \infty)$.

Comment: What about using the fact that $$\|x-p\|=d(x,U)=\min_{u\in U}\|x-u\|$$
Can we implies that $\angle(x,p)=\displaystyle\min_{0\ne u\in U}\angle(x,u)$ from that fact ?