# Degree of the orthogonal Projection is minimal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I hope someone can help me out.

If I have a finite dimensional vectorspace V and a subspace U, how do I show that for a given x out of V (which isn't already orthogonal to U), that the orthogonal projection p of x onto U has the smallest degree with x out of all the vectors of the subspace U?

I'm sorry for my English, I hope you can understand what I mean :)

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315138/265466.

Comment: You can’t prove this because it’s false. For any vector $y$ and positive scalar $\lambda$, $y$ and $\lambda y$ make the same angle with $x$, so there is no *unique* vector that minimizes this angle.